# Vaadin - drag & drop with control key

Tags: java, vaadin

Is it possible to find out if some key is pressed during dragging in vaadin? I would like if user could copy item by dragging with pressed Ctrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drop method just use this:

```
TreeTargetDetails treeTargetDetails = 
    ((TreeTargetDetails) event.getTargetDetails());
MouseEventDetails mouseEventDetails =
    MouseEventDetails.deSerialize((String) treeTargetDetails.getData("mouseEvent"));

if (mouseEventDetails.isCtrlKey())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Matti from Vaadin forum, help me with this https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/7615708/7615707